# Android-Expandable List view

Tags: android

How to move the group item to left when you deleted the default group indicator by using setGroupIndicator() method.

Comment: How did you move it right before?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to adjust your TextView to the left by 36dip (assuming you're using the standard group indicator from android)

```
<TextView android:paddingLeft="36dip"/>
```

I did this in my own project, hope it helps :)

Comment: i am not asking left to right. i want the text alignment starting from zeroth(x=0) position.

Comment: hmm sorry, misunderstood the question :|